# Extents reported in USN_RECORD_V4 struct are a lot bigger than actual changes

Tags: windows, winapi, usn

We use USN change journal to track changes on SQL data files for performing incremental backups.

For big files (of size 5 TB), we have seen USN_RECORD_V4 have extents reporting that a big portion of file is modified but actual change on the file is very less.

I want to understand how and when USN_RECORD_EXTENT are added to a USN_RECORD_V4.

In what scenarios is it possible that data is not overwritten but there is an extent added in USN_RECORD_V4.

On one day, I observed, 943 records for a file of size 5 TB. Of these 943 records, there are three consecutive records for this file which had extents which corresponds to changed data of around 330 GB, 220 GB and 4300 GB. All other 940 records combined reported 70 GB data is changed.

But actual change of that file is only of 600 GB (We did a diff between file backups of the two versions of file at 16KB granularity). So, the three big records corresponds to some actual changes in the file but are reporting some very big extents which are not modified.

Due to this, our backup software is doing way more work than what it should.

Answer (score 0):

> how and when USN_RECORD_EXTENT are added to a USN_RECORD_V4.

`Reason` flags that identify reasons for changes that have accumulated in this file or directory journal record since the file or directory opened.

I suggest you could check the `Reason` of records.

> In what scenarios is it possible that data is not overwritten but there is an extent added in USN_RECORD_V4.

According to the Doc: [Change Journal Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/change-journal-records)

multiple changes to the same file may result in only one reason flag being added to the current record. If the same kind of change occurs more than once, the NTFS file system does not write a new record for the changes after the first.

Comment: Upon experiments, I found the reason to be dynamic increase in chunk size by NTFS if number of modified extents becomes more than 8193. For the volume, I've set chunk size to be 16KB for range tracking. But, if number of modified extents in a file is a lot, ntfs simple increases chunk size to try to reduce number of extents.

Do you know how this can be disabled so I can get the exact changes (at 16 KB) without ntfs increasing the chunk size?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it is by design. And there is no winapi to disable NTFS dynamic increase in chunk size.

Comment: There was one more thing. NTFS adds a USN v3 close record every 30 min even if the file is not closed. That event resets the modified extents which it stores in memory because with usn v3 close record all modified extents are flushed as usn v4 records. Is there a way to change the 30 min frequency to say 15 min frequency. With this, there will be less chances of many changes in the file in 15 min as compared to 30 min. I asked this specifically in another question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77623104/ntfs-change-journal-usn-v3-close-record-added-every-30-min

Comment: According to your description, it is related to NTFS and it's out of the support scope of WinAPI.