# NTFS change journal USN v3 close record added every 30 min

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, usn

I've a program which opens the file with write permissions and keeps it open for few hours. It modifies the file every minute. When I check USN journal for this file, it shows a USN V3 record with DATA_OVERWRITE|CLOSE flag set every 30 min. The program is not closing the file at all in between.

It looks like NTFS is adding a close record to flush all the change extents as USN v4 records every 30 min. Is there a way to configure this frequency of 30 min?

The reason I want to configure is because when there are too many extents which are modified, ntfs increases the chunk size to reduce number of extents in memory. If modified extents are flushed as v4 records more often, chances of ntfs increasing chunk size will decrease.